# How to connect to mysql on a server

Tags: mysql

My uncle gave me access to his server so I could play around with mysql and php. He installed php and mysql on it created a user as well folder for me to play around in. I was wondering how to access mysql from my laptop. I am using filezilla to connect to the server, through ssh. Do I need a client version that connects to the server or anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several applications for mysql access, below are free ones.

mac os -> sequel pro www.sequelpro.com
windows -> sqlyog community https://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list